# How to check docker service logs when restart and stop by: sudo systemctle restart docker or sudo systemctl stop docker?

Tags: docker, systemctl

I have an ubuntu 18.04 running on a metal server. My docker working good but one day i can not build new docker image, my build script hang without showing any error (the script working good before).

I tried to restart docker engine by: `sudo systemctl restart docker` but docker service can not active, the command: `sudo systemcle stop docker` not working too.

Then **i rebooted** my server then docker go back.

What **log files** should i check to know what make my docker service hang?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the docker service logs using:

```
sudo journalctl -fu docker.service
```